# How to Prevent Form Submit/Return Error when Drop Down Field Selections are Identical

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I am trying to create a Workshop Preference Selection form - users indicate which workshops they are interested in attending during various Sessions at a conference. As we use an algorithm to assign people workshops based on their preferences, we want to make sure that someone select 5 **unique** workshops per Session. They are allowed to select the same workshop if it is in different Sessions, but cannot have identical Workshops selected from the dropdown menus in each individual Session. None of the code I have attempted to write is having any impact, and I cannot figure out the appropriate route to take.

I tried to create an if x === y statement that would prevent form submission and also generate a explanation after the guilty fields, but to no avail. I'm also struggling with integrating this within the confines of FormAssembly, since I do not have access to edit the raw HTML/actively deployed Javascript, which is why I tried the preventDefault route.

This was my most recent attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#4734014").submit(function (event) {
        var submit = true;

        termsIsChecked = 
        sOneFirst = $("#tfa_4").val();
        sOneSecond = $("tfa_13").val();

        if (sOneFirst === SOneSecond) {
            $("#tfa_4").after("<p>Please choose each workshop only once per Session.</p>");
            submit = false;
        }

        if (submit === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the Test Form I've been working with:
https://www.tfaforms.com/4734014

The above code only attempts to prevent form submission if Session 1 First Choice and Second Choice are identical. Rating 1 and Rating 2 (etc.) should be allowed to be identical. Eventually, I'd like First Choice to be prevented from being identical to both Second and Third Choices within Session 1.

Comment: I'm thinking one way would be to create an empty array onsubmit and then iterate over all the values and store them all in the array. In the loop you could check if that value is already in the array, if it is it means it has selected the same thing twice

Comment: This is not what you had suggested, but something else I had tried as well. Currently fiddling with empty array... `document.getElementById("4734014").submit(); {
  function compareSubmit() {
 var one= document.getElementByID("tfa_4");
 var onecomp= getElementByID(one).value.innerHTML;
 var two= document.getElementByID("tfa_13");
 var twocomp= getElementByID(one).value.innerHTML;
   
if (onecomp == twocomp ){
     $("#tfa_4").after("<p>Please choose each workshop only once per Session.</p>");
      }else{
     return false;
      }
  }
};`

Comment: You're comparing val() s which are different for each select option, so they will never tell you they're the same

Comment: I see. I was trying to get it to call the innerHTML value, or in other words the text inside the menu itself to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a shot, only thing I modified in the HTML is that I added a data-attribute to the selects options.

I never send the form in my JS, instead I throw a message in the console when the user selects the same thing twice.

Here's how it works:
On form submit I create an empty array for every fieldset, then for every select in every fieldset, I check if the selected option is already in that array: if not, everything's fine and I store the current selected option in it, otherwise it means the user has already selected that option and I throw out an error.

Hope it helps somehow..

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  var $sections = $("fieldset.section");
  $sections.each(function(i) {
   var $selects = $(this).find("select");
    var selectedValues = [];
    $selects.each(function(s) {
     var value = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-value');
      if(value !== undefined) {
       if(selectedValues.indexOf(value) > -1) {
        console.log("Error, value already selected")
       } else {
        selectedValues.push(value);
       }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="https://www.tfaforms.com/responses/processor" class="hintsBelow labelsAbove" id="4734014" role="form">
<fieldset id="tfa_8" class="section">
<legend id="tfa_8-L">Session 1<br></legend>
<div id="tfa_37" class="section inline group">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_4-D">
<label id="tfa_4-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_4">First Choice<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_4" name="tfa_4" title="First Choice" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_5" id="tfa_5" class="" data-value="choice-a">Choice A</option>
<option value="tfa_6" id="tfa_6" class="" data-value="choice-b">Choice B</option>
<option value="tfa_7" id="tfa_7" class="" data-value="choice-c">Choice C</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_29-D">
<label id="tfa_29-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_29">Rating 1<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_29" name="tfa_29" title="Rating 1" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_34" id="tfa_34" class="">Highest</option>
<option value="tfa_35" id="tfa_35" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="tfa_36" id="tfa_36" class="">Lowest</option></select></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tfa_54" class="section inline group">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_13-D">
<label id="tfa_13-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_13">Second Choice<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_13" name="tfa_13" title="Second Choice" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_14" id="tfa_14" class="" data-value="choice-a">Choice A</option>
<option value="tfa_15" id="tfa_15" class="" data-value="choice-b">Choice B</option>
<option value="tfa_16" id="tfa_16" class="" data-value="choice-c">Choice C</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_42-D">
<label id="tfa_42-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_42">Rating 2<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_42" name="tfa_42" title="Rating 2" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_43" id="tfa_43" class="">Highest</option>
<option value="tfa_44" id="tfa_44" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="tfa_45" id="tfa_45" class="">Lowest</option></select></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tfa_55" class="section inline group">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_21-D">
<label id="tfa_21-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_21">Third Choice<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_21" name="tfa_21" title="Third Choice" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_22" id="tfa_22" class="" data-value="choice-a">Choice A</option>
<option value="tfa_23" id="tfa_23" class="" data-value="choice-b">Choice B</option>
<option value="tfa_24" id="tfa_24" class="" data-value="choice-c">Choice C</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_50-D">
<label id="tfa_50-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_50">Rating 3<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_50" name="tfa_50" title="Rating 3" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_51" id="tfa_51" class="">Highest</option>
<option value="tfa_52" id="tfa_52" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="tfa_53" id="tfa_53" class="">Lowest</option></select></div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="tfa_84" class="section">
<legend id="tfa_84-L">Session 2<br></legend>
<div id="tfa_85" class="section inline group">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_86-D">
<label id="tfa_86-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_86">First Choice<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_86" name="tfa_86" title="First Choice" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_87" id="tfa_87" class="" data-value="choice-a">Choice A</option>
<option value="tfa_88" id="tfa_88" class="" data-value="choice-b">Choice B</option>
<option value="tfa_89" id="tfa_89" class="" data-value="choice-c">Choice C</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_90-D">
<label id="tfa_90-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_90">Rating 1<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_90" name="tfa_90" title="Rating 1" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_91" id="tfa_91" class="">Highest</option>
<option value="tfa_92" id="tfa_92" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="tfa_93" id="tfa_93" class="">Lowest</option></select></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tfa_94" class="section inline group">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_95-D">
<label id="tfa_95-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_95">Second Choice<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_95" name="tfa_95" title="Second Choice" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_96" id="tfa_96" class="" data-value="choice-a">Choice A</option>
<option value="tfa_97" id="tfa_97" class="" data-value="choice-b">Choice B</option>
<option value="tfa_98" id="tfa_98" class="" data-value="choice-c">Choice C</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_99-D">
<label id="tfa_99-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_99">Rating 2<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_99" name="tfa_99" title="Rating 2" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_100" id="tfa_100" class="">Highest</option>
<option value="tfa_101" id="tfa_101" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="tfa_102" id="tfa_102" class="">Lowest</option></select></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tfa_103" class="section inline group">
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_104-D">
<label id="tfa_104-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_104">Third Choice<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_104" name="tfa_104" title="Third Choice" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_105" id="tfa_105" class="" data-value="choice-a">Choice A</option>
<option value="tfa_106" id="tfa_106" class="" data-value="choice-b">Choice B</option>
<option value="tfa_107" id="tfa_107" class="" data-value="choice-c">Choice C</option></select></div>
</div>
<div class="oneField field-container-D    " id="tfa_108-D">
<label id="tfa_108-L" class="label preField reqMark" for="tfa_108">Rating 3<br></label><br><div class="inputWrapper"><select id="tfa_108" name="tfa_108" title="Rating 3" aria-required="true" class="required"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="tfa_109" id="tfa_109" class="">Highest</option>
<option value="tfa_110" id="tfa_110" class="">Medium</option>
<option value="tfa_111" id="tfa_111" class="">Lowest</option></select></div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions" id="4734014-A"><input type="submit" data-label="Submit" class="primaryAction" id="submit_button" value="Submit"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<input type="hidden" value="675-5f6788ccfe08d81db14e4237e150e28a" name="tfa_dbCounters" id="tfa_dbCounters" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" value="4734014" name="tfa_dbFormId" id="tfa_dbFormId"><input type="hidden" value="" name="tfa_dbResponseId" id="tfa_dbResponseId"><input type="hidden" value="eb5a2798b7c6daacfd3a4578060050f6" name="tfa_dbControl" id="tfa_dbControl"><input type="hidden" value="1554993064" name="tfa_dbTimeStarted" id="tfa_dbTimeStarted" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" value="7" name="tfa_dbVersionId" id="tfa_dbVersionId"><input type="hidden" value="" name="tfa_switchedoff" id="tfa_switchedoff">
</form>
```